# map server recommendation

Tags: image

I am looking for a server to host [World Wind](http://worldwind.arc.nasa.gov/) for private use, the World Wind Project is using two Sun SunFire 4500 and two Sun Blade X8420 servers [(see here)](http://worldwind.arc.nasa.gov/java/server/readme.html) for their hosting needs, but this is way beyond what I have in mind.  What would you recommend for a reasonable server to host something like this?  There will be approximately 4TB of map data, possibly more.

Comment: Product and service recommendations are specifically off topic for ServerFault (see point 4 in the NOT About section of the [FAQ](http://serverfault.com/faq))

Answer (score 1):

The hardware reqs state it can run on a laptop, so anything above this will *work*, of course the more hardware you throw at it the quicker it should be so just look at your budget and spend wisely. Good luck, sounds like a fun project.

edit - Oh and I may as well do my usual and recommend just getting a HP DL380 G6 - they're like the VW Beetle of servers - a workhorse that does a good job of most jobs :)

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned that your World Wind server is for PRIVATE use but you didn't mention what type of load you're planning on putting on it.

If your load isn't going to be all that great and all you really need is 4TB of storage you might be able to get away with a cheap 1U or 2U rackmount server and some cheap 1TB hard drives.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking at blades, you might want to consider IBM's HS12s.  Or rackmounts like the x3650 M2.